# nested scrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

I am new to iphone development . Can anyone please tell me how to add a vertical scrollview inside a horizontal scroll view. I went through many samples but couldn't get a clear picture about it . I wan my view to be scrolled in both vertical and horizontal directions. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code for scrolling:

EDIT: Here is my code for scrolling

```
  self.firstScroll.pagingEnabled=YES;

 self.firstScroll.clipsToBounds=YES;

   int numberOfViews=3;

 for(int i=0;i<numberOfViews;i++){

    CGFloat xOrigin=self.view.frame.size.width*i;

    UIView *awesomeView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,        self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    awesomeView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [self.firstScroll addSubview:awesomeView];
 }
self.firstScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*numberOfViews,     self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:firstScroll];


self.nextVerticalScroll.pagingEnabled=YES;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfViews ;i++){
    CGFloat yOrigin=self.view.frame.size.height * i;
    UIView *verticalView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yOrigin, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
  verticalView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [self.nextVerticalScroll addSubview:verticalView];
}
self.nextVerticalScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height*numberOfViews);
[self.view addSubview:nextVerticalScroll];
```

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any tests? Such as creating one scroll view then roatate it and then add another scroll view inside the rotated scroll view, or throwing your computer...somthing...

Comment: Hi, I have put my code in the EDIT

Comment: `UIScrollView` allows for scrolling in both directions... why are you using two?

Comment: can u please tell me in detail how to do this. sorry for the lack of knowledge

Comment: Right now you're setting contentSize to have a width of `self.view.frame.size.width`. If you set it to be `self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViewsHorizontal`, or something like that, you'll get your horizontal scrolling, too.

Comment: I have tried it, but no result .What i want exactly is a view with both horizontal and vertical scrolling.What i am getting no is only one scroll even though I have put two scrollviews

Comment: You only want one scrollview, and set its content size to be both taller and wider than the bounds of the scrollview. See the example in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to have scrollviews within scrollviews because you can't control which gets the horizontal gestures and which gets the vertical gestures (without a lot of hassle, at least). It is much easier to have a single scrollview with a `contentSize` that is bigger horizontally and vertically than the `bounds` of the scrollview itself, e.g.:

```
- (void)configureScrollView
{
    NSInteger rows = 4;
    NSInteger cols = 5;

    CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;

    // configure my scroll view itself

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width * cols, height * rows);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    // now let's add the labels to the scrollview

    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (NSInteger col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            // making my label just a little smaller than the scrollview's bounds so I can easily see the scrolling/paging

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake((width * col) + 20.0, (height * row) + 20.0, width - 40.0, height - 40.0); 

            // create and configure the label

            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", row * cols + col + 1.0];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

            // add it to my scrollview

            [self.scrollView addSubview:label];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just filling my scroll view with 20 different text labels (and colored the background of the scrollview differently from the labels so I could see them), but it demonstrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please if you have added Paging in XIB then remove it...I think it will help you.